# Using VPN on Ubuntu Server

Tags: openvpn

I'm running Ubuntu 16 on my server. Works fine; I've got several services running that are accessible throughout my home network.

The issue is that I installed OpenVPN and it seems anytime I start the service, the server will cease any internet activity and only be accessible from within the LAN, meaning SMB and SSH protocols are still active.

When I SSH, I run `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com` to verify my IP address is indeed different from my ISP assigned DHCP or if it's down.

I've restarted the network service using `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`, but still get the same issue.

I've also verified my iptables and they are set to default.

What could be causing the issue of losing the internet connectivity? I can only think that it is the router issued by the ISP that's causing this.

**Update** 
ip route results:

```
ip route get 4.2.2.1
4.2.2.1 via 10.63.10.5 dev tun0  src 10.63.10.6
    cache

ip route get 192.168.0.1
192.168.0.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.0.109
    cache
```

I have also disabled the firewall (`ufw disable` and then `ufw enable`) and renabled it to rule it out.

Comment: Please include the output of ip route (and ip -6 route if you have IPv6). I guess that the default gateway changes...

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: I meant the output from the command 'ip route' without any arguments. Sorry if it was unclear :) What I guess is happening is that your default route is changed to the VPN, so when you get a incoming packet from the Internet, via NAT, you cannot reply to that in a meaningful way.